# Programa para listar os numeros primos menores ou igual ao valor de entrada

Tags: c

Bom dia, estou querendo imprimir um conjunto aos quais devo imprimir apenas os números primos menores ou igual ao valor de entrada, porém não consigo ter êxito, pois ele sempre retorna o valor n e n-1, com a exceção do número 1 (que não é primo). Queria saber o que falta pra esse código consiga reconhecer o while e imprimir apenas os números primos.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n,res,i,j;
    printf("insira o seu numero aqui\n") 
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Voce inseriu este numero: %d \n",n);
        for (i=n;i>=0;i--){
        res=1;
        j=2;
                    if (i<=1){
                    res=0;
                    while (res==1 && j<=i/2)
                        if (i&j==0)
                        res=0;
                    j++;
                }
                if(res==1)
                printf("%d ",i);
 }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não vejo sentido neste teste: `if (i<=1){`. Aqui: `while (res==1 && j<=i/2) if (i&j==0) res=0;` pode entrar em loop infinito. O algoritmo utilizado não verifica se o número é primo.

Comment: Mas nao entrou e nem ao menos apareceu no print. 
Quando fiz esse algoritmo apenas recebendo o valor pelo usuario pra saber se eh primo ou nao ele funcionou. Quando tentei adicionar um for e o while recebendo o n-1 de for ele n funcionou. Sou bem iniciante em C. Logo fica essa confusao.

Comment: Eu tava na logica em:

Eu dou o valor
A cada numero feito o teste se ele eh primo.
Quem eh primo ele eh impresso
Assim que eh feito o teste ele vai diminuindo ate zero
repete.

Comment: Aqui: `if (i&j==0)` eu não sei qual o resultado espera obter deste Bitwise AND.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Veja se é isto o que deseja:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n, res, i, j;
    printf("Insira o seu numero aqui: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Voce inseriu este numero: %d \n",n);
    for (i=n; i>1; i--) {
        int j=2;
        while ((j <= i/2) && (i%j != 0))
            j++;
        if (j>i/2)
            printf("%d ",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente nao. 
Ele sequer faz a listagem dos números, somente imprime o n no comeco do algoritmo. Mas obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Corrigido, estava utilizando `n` no lugar de `i` na verificação da primalidade.

Comment: Muito grato! Resolveu minha duvida :)